# Creating tabs like opera in javafx

Tags: css, javafx-2

I want to create tabs like opera web browser in my JavaFx 2.0 App. I tried to customize the tab with many CSS settings, but didn't succeed. Does anybody know how to do that?

Comment: Can you elaborate "tabs like Opera" termin? There are several variants of them.

Answer (score 2):

You can add a class to an individual Tab to style it, like this:

```
.blue .tab-label  {
  -fx-text-fill: blue;  
}

.red .tab-label  {
 -fx-text-fill: red;  
}

.green .tab-label {
-fx-text-fill: lime;  
}
```

And to style all tabs you can use a CSS like this:

```
.tab-chat.tab:hover {
-fx-background-color:  linear-gradient(to top, -fx-purple, -fx-control-inner-background);
}

.tab-chat:selected {
-fx-background-color: linear-gradient(to bottom, derive(-fx-base, 95%),     -fx-control-inner-background );
-fx-background-insets: 0, 9 9 0 9;
-fx-background-radius: 12 12 0 0, 12 12 0 0;
-fx-font-weight: bold;
}

/* ----------------------------- */
/*  Tabs  background graphic     */
/* ----------------------------- */
.tab-header-background {
   -fx-background-image: url("images/back-rustyfill.jpg");
}
```